# Sorting a Vector with std::sort

Tags: c++

I got a vector containing pairs. My pairs have template parameters.

```
std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2> > myVector;
```

I would like to sort myVector by the pairs second data tag, so by the "value"(T2), not the "key"(T1).
I saw [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) that i can use this sweet method:

```
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), mySortingFunc);
```

and this is my sortFunc:

```
bool mySortingFunc (std::pair<T1, T2> pair1,   std::pair<T1, T2> pair2){ 
     return (pair1.second<pair2.second); 
}
```

and its not compiling, throwing me 10 kilometers long error. (i use g++)
Any advice how should i do this?

- E D I T:

Actual code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class OrderedMMap
{

std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2> > myVector;

public:

bool sortFunc (std::pair<T1, T2> pair1,   std::pair<T1, T2> pair2) { 

    return (pair1.second<pair2.second); 
}

void sortIt()
{
    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), sortFunc);
}
};
```

Comment: Post the *actual* code and the error messages generated by the compiler.

Comment: Does T2 have the `<` operator implemented?

Comment: Also, what is `T2`? Does `operator<` exist for this type?

Comment: T2 is appareantly std::string so i guess its not important YET. Something else is the problem.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: Why don't you post the actual code? Your question has no clue to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sortFunc` is a *non-static* member function. That is the problem. A non-static member function can be invoked only on an object of the class; `std::sort` cannot do that for you.

The easy fix is to make the function `static`:

```
static bool sortFunc (std::pair<T1, T2> pair1,   std::pair<T1, T2> pair2) { 
    return (pair1.second<pair2.second); 
}
```

With the `static` keyword, now it became just like regular function, which can be invoked without class instance, which means `std::sort` will work now.

It would be good if the function accepts the arguments by const reference:

```
static bool sortFunc(std::pair<T1,T2> const& p1,std::pair<T1,T2> const& p2) 
{ 
    return p1.second < p2.second; 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just wanted to tell the fact that you told me in one keyword "static", g++ told me in a 3 page error message :)